# JMeter: How to benchmark data deletion from database table in batches?

Tags: jmeter, sql-delete, database-performance

I am trying to compare the performance difference between DELETE batch sizes using JMeter.

I have a table which I populate with a large amount of test data. Next, I have a JDBC Request that runs the following statement:

```
delete from tbl where (entry_dt < '2019-02-01') and (rownum <= 10000);
```

I want to keep running this until the table is empty, and record the time taken to clear the table.

I will run this thread multiple times to get an average execution time, and repeat this process for different batch sizes.

1. How should I define my While Controller to achieve this?
2. I read from other sites that I can use a Transaction Controller to time my process, but I am not familiar with this feature. How should I define my Transaction Controller to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) to be a top level test element under the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Add [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) as a child of the Transaction Controller and use the following condition expression:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${count_1} > 0,)}
   ```
3. Put your JDBC Request sampler as a child of the While Controller
4. Add [JDBC PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler and configure it like:

   [image]
5. That's it, While Controller will iterate until there are entries in the `tbl` table and the Transaction Controller will record the cumulative time of all JDBC Request samplers executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

1. Use the "JDBC Request - Get Count" sampler to get the data from the db which has to be deleted [image: Get Count]
2. Use a BeanShell Assertion to check if there is more data that can be deleted. Otherwise stop the thread [image: BeanShell Assertion]
3. Execute the request to delete the data [image: Delete the data]
4. Thread Group should stop Test on error [image: Stop test on error]