# JMeter: while controller not terminating upon zero count

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

This is a continuation of my question [JMeter: How to benchmark data deletion from database table in batches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740549/jmeter-how-to-benchmark-data-deletion-from-database-table-in-batches). I adopted the solution proposed by Dimitri T, and now I am using the test case for Oracle DB.

My test case starts by inserting 1000 entries, using 100 threads in 10 loops. After that, it deletes where `rownum < 250`.

However, my test case is no longer able to detect that the table is empty. When I view the response data in my result tree, I see the following:

```
249 updates
249 updates
249 updates
249 updates
4 updates
0 updates
0 updates
0 updates
...
```

JMeter itself does not report any errors occurring.

My thread group looks like this:

```
...(separate thread group to do INSERT)...

Thread Group: Do DELETE
   Txn Ctrl: DELETE
      While Loop: tbl still has data
         JDBC Request: DELETE from tbl
            JDBC PostProcessor
```

Loop condition is defined as follows:

```
${__jexl3('${count_1} > 0',)}
```

(As a slight change from the solution in my previous question, I surrounded the condition in quotes to prevent the ambiguous expression error from showing up.)

JDBC request is defined as follows:

```
delete from tbl where (entrydt < ${endDt}) and (rownum < ${deleteLimit})
```

(User-defined variables `endDt` and `deleteLimit` have values `TO_DATE('2019/02/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')` and `250` respectively.)

JDBC post-procesor is defined as follows:

```
[Select statement] select count(*) from tbl

Variable names: count (All other fields are empty.)
Handle ResultSet: Store as String
```

I have tried

- Changing the loop condition; the quotes do not matter; neither do changing `${count_1}` to `${count}`
- Changing the post-processor; between variable names, result variable name, and how the result set is handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

who told you to surround the expression with quotation marks? First you break the working solution and then you're complaining that the expression provided doesn't work.

Just define `count_1` as as positive number via [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) and you will not have any errors in *jmeter.log*

If for some reason you're not willing to do this or cannot do this - you can consider migrating to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) with an extra check of `count_1` variable being set like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('count_1') == null || (vars.get('count_1') as int) > 0,)}
```

Comment: In the previous solution, I belatedly noticed the ambiguous expression exception in JMeter. Surrounding it with quotes fixed the exception without breaking the solution, so I carried that forward.